# How can I write a formula so that I can prorate and annualise data for current and following years?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a seemingly easy issue that has been taking most of my time lately at work.

I am trying to do sort of an user form with VBA to input data. I have done the VBA part with no problems.

The second part of my task is that from the data provided, I need to use it as "forecast" or extrapolate it for future years.

I am trying to write a formula that when the data is inserted, the formula would automatically fill in the rest. So far I have done the first part, I can make it work from my current year up to the last one in the "forecast".

[Full current year](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5uX0.jpg)

The prorated for current year depending on the month in the delivery date:

[Prorated for month then annualised](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQdnY.jpg)

My problem starts when I try to put data of future deliveries, the data gets annualised for the year in which the benefit is delivered which is good, but the problem is that for the previous years, it should not read anything in fact since it is the past, I cannot count with money from the past when something is delivered in 2020 for example:

[Data entered in future but previous years show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ryw2A.jpg)

the formula in question is this:

```
=IF($H5="Annual",IF($I5>R$3,((12-((MONTH($I5))-4))/12)*$K5,$K5),IF($H5="One Off",IF($I5<R$3+365,IF($I5>R3,$K5,""),"")))
```

When the cell reads "One Off" however it works properly, the amount only shows up in the corresponding year, even if in the future.

I do not know what to do know to make it work, I have tried many modifications to the formula but none has worked, for example:

```
=IF($H5="Annual",IF($I5>R$3,$R$40,IF(I5<R3-365,$K5)),IF($H5="One Off",IF($I5<R$3+365,IF($I5>R3,$K5,""),"")))
```

R40 is just nested if formulas, a long way to prorate then annualise:

```
=IF(MONTH(I5)=4,M5*12,IF(MONTH(I5)=5,M5*11,IF(MONTH(I5)=6,M5*10,IF(MONTH(I5)=7,M5*9,IF(MONTH(I5)=8,M5*8,IF(MONTH(I5)=9,M5*7,IF(MONTH(I5)=10,M5*6,IF(MONTH(I5)=11,M5*5,IF(MONTH(I5)=12,M5*4,IF(MONTH(I5)=1,M5*3,IF(MONTH(I5)=2,M5*2,IF(MONTH(I5)=3,M5))))))))))))
```

Any suggestions are welcomed, this is relay doing my head in.

To summarise;

- I need the formula to fill  in the date for current year and future years if the delivery date is in the current year (ie 2018 then fill in for the future years) **This part works**
- I need the formula to fill in the data for current year of the benefit delivered but at the same time, if this is delivered say in 2020, I need the formula to **NOT fill in data for the previous years** ie 2018, 2019.

Please ignore the cells that read FALSE those are old formulas for when I was trying different things.

Thank you.

Comment: =IF($H5="Annual",IF($I5>R$3,$R$40,IF(I5<R3-365,$K5)),IF($H5="One Off",IF($I5<R$3+365,IF($I5>R3,$K5,""),"")))

I do not know why the above formula was cut short in my message.

Answer (score 1):

No need to reply now, I found the solution, it is as follows:

`=IF(OR(ISBLANK($H5),ISBLANK($I5),ISBLANK($K5))," ",IF($H5="Annual",IF($I5<R$3+365,IF($I5>R$3,$A$1,$K5),""),IF($H5="One Off",IF($I5<R$3+365,IF($I5>R$3,$K5,""),""))))`

A1 is just a cell referring to a nested if formula because the previous formula that I had, worked until certain months, A1 is as follows:

```
=IF(MONTH(I5)=4,M5*12,IF(MONTH(I5)=5,M5*11,IF(MONTH(I5)=6,M5*10,IF(MONTH(I5)=7,M5*9,IF(MONTH(I5)=8,M5*8,IF(MONTH(I5)=9,M5*7,IF(MONTH(I5)=10,M5*6,IF(MONTH(I5)=11,M5*5,IF(MONTH(I5)=12,M5*4,IF(MONTH(I5)=1,M5*3,IF(MONTH(I5)=2,M5*2,IF(MONTH(I5)=3,M5))))))))))))
```

It is just a long way to annualise X amount if it is an annual value, delivered during X month in the year.

The ISBLANK functions are just so "FALSE" does not show in the cells when I copied the formula down.